# Can I set Truecrypt options from terminal?

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, truecrypt

When trying to dismount an encrypted partition i get the ol'
`Error: device-mapper: remove ioctl failed: Device or resource busy`. The recommended solution from the interwebz seems to be to change some truecrypt settings to not use kernel cryptographic services.

This would be easy to try, if it weren't for the fact that the system has precisely no window managers installed.

Is there a way to change the truecrypt setting "Do not use kernel cryptographic services" from the terminal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to `truecrypt -h`:

```
-m, --mount-options=OPTION1[,OPTION2,OPTION3,...]
 Specifies comma-separated mount options for a TrueCrypt volume:
  headerbak: Use backup headers when mounting a volume.
  nokernelcrypto: Do not use kernel cryptographic services.
  readonly|ro: Mount volume as read-only.
  system: Mount partition using system encryption.
  timestamp|ts: Do not restore host-file modification timestamp when a volume
   is dismounted (note that the operating system under certain circumstances
   does not alter host-file timestamps, which may be mistakenly interpreted
   to mean that this option does not work).
 See also option --fs-options.
```

So, try this:

```
truecrypt -t -m=nokernelcrypto volume mountpoint
```